# How to design Netty Server for multiple output type

Tags: netty, nio

As in http we can implement multiple urls to perform different actions.  How can we achieve the same thing with a Netty Server? 
More explicitly, I have to output lets say four types of google protobuf from the netty server depending on the request (which are also of 4 types). Should I create separate Netty Server for each request type or should I have different handlers in the same pipeline? In the later case I would have to have atleast 4*3 = 12 handlers (For every request type an inbound protobuf handler, an outbound protobuf handler and a business logic handler). Is it a good design?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few different design options with different trade-offs to consider.

1. **Server per request/response type.**  Each call with a distinct request/response type is handled by its own dedicated Netty server.  Fine-grained servers like this would fit a [microservices architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microservices), and in general, you'd likely inherit the pros and cons of that architecture.  Good build and deployment automation are pre-requisities to make this successful.  Otherwise, you'll end up with extra work building, deploying and configuring multiple servers.
2. **Handler per request/response type.**  Run a single Netty server with distinct handlers per request/response type.  The multiple handlers are decoupled from one another, which can make long-term maintenance easier.  You might consider setting up your own abstract base class implementing [`ChannelHandler`](https://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/channel/ChannelHandler.html) if you want some common logic across all handlers, such as common error handling.  Then, all of the specific handlers would subclass that.  As you have noted, there is a potential downside in that it leads to a proliferation of many classes, which might harm readability for people unfamiliar with the codebase.
3. **Single handler for multiple request/response types.**  You could write a single Netty handler for all request/response types.  Internally, it would need to introspect on the request type (using `instanceof` or some kind of type descriminator field within the request object) and then dispatch to the appropriate logic for that request.  This fits the [front controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_controller) pattern.  Compared to multiple handlers, this avoids the proliferation of multiple classes.  The potential downside is that the dispatch logic can turn into a monolithic nested `if-else` or `switch-case` structure that must be maintained carefully every time new request/response types are added.

In my experience, I've had success with both options 2 and 3, depending on the number of distinct request/response types in the API.  For a relatively small number, a single handler works well, and the dispatch logic doesn't become too cumbersome to maintain.  For a wide API footprint, it starts to become helpful to organize it into distinct handlers.  There also can be hybrid approaches that still use multiple handlers, but each handler covers a group of multiple related request/response types.

A micro-services architecture like option 1 can be attractive if you can get the sophistication in the build and deployment tools.  If you can't invest in that tooling though, then it might just generate a lot of extra work.